# Typescript interface

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I have a typescript interface:

```
export interface LatLng {
  constructor(lat: number, lng: number): void;
  lat(): number;
  lng(): number;
}
```

And array with a type of LatLng:

```
path: Array<LatLng>;
```

How can i push elements to this array ?

Comment: Do you actually have a class like that? Where is the implementation of this constructor?

Comment: No implementation. How can I implement this interface in class ?

Answer (score 2):

Implement interface

```
export class LatLngNew implements LatLng {
 constructor(public lat: number, public lng: number) {}
}
```

You can write like this

```
this.path.push(new LatLngNew(2,3))
```

Also you can define array type like this

```
path: LatLng[];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have an interface then you should not have the `constructor` there and it should look like this:

```
export interface LatLng {
    lat(): number;
    lng(): number;
}
```

You can then push a new item like so:

```
path.push({
    lat: function() { return 0; },
    lng: function() { return 0; },
});
```

You can also create a factory function for it:

```
function createLatLng(lat: number, lng: number): LatLng {
    return {
        lat: function() { return lat; },
        lng: function() { return lng; }
    };
}
```

If you want a class then you do it like so:

```
class LatLng {
    constructor(private _lat: number, private _lng: number) {}

    lat() {
        return this._lat;
    }

    lng() {
        return this._lng;
    }
}
```

And push a new instance like so:

```
path.push(new LatLng(0, 0));
```

Comment: I did't create this interface. https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/interfaces/LatLng.html#source. But I need to use this interface as a type and give elements.

Comment: Oh, it's an existing library, ok then the implementation probably already exists and you are only talking about the types. The other answer by @alexKhymenko should work for you then

Comment: Answer by @alexKhymenko doesn't work. It shows error: '''LatLng' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and add more of your code, how you use this type and so on